# Finding unused ByRef parameters in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, reflection

I have recently converted a project from VB6 to VB.NET. As part of the conversion process, most functions have had their parameters marked as `ByRef`. For instance, I have this function:

```
Function HexToDec(ByRef HexValue As String) As Short
    HexToDec = Val("&H" & HexValue)
End Function
```

Even though the parameter `HexValue` is marked as `ByRef`, it is not being assigned to in the function. Removing the `ByRef` keyword would not change how the function works.

Most of the functions in my project are like this, however some do make use of the `ByRef` functionality.

Are there any good ways to find all functions where `ByRef` is unnecessary? In particular, I wonder if there is a method using reflection to determine if certain fields are never assigned to.

Comment: I don't know a way to have this automated, unfortunately. However, VS 2010 and later versions have a cool feature that highlights all occurrences of a symbol, when you step on it. It should greatly reduce the amount of effort you need to invest, just hop over each parameter of the function and see if it's being assigned to, you only need to scan highlighted words.

Comment: @MattWilko It's causing lots of problems to crop up in unexpected places when read only properties are passed to the functions. Somehow this doesn't error in the VB6 version, but does in the .NET version.

Comment: Ok that's a fair point I can understand why that might fail

Comment: ByRef was the default in VB6, very unlikely that you'd ever really needed it.  A tool can never accurately make the call, there are also high odds that, even if you assigned the argument in the procedure that you never actually relied on the value propagating back to the caller and being used there.  You really do need the tool between your ears to do it right.  Just a blanket Search + Replace is likely to do it 99.9% correct.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like theres no easy way to do this. However, my project is pretty big, so I didn't want to do in manually. I wrote a little tool to help - maybe it'll be useful for someone.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<string> inUse = new List<string>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var loc = @"C:\Users\Owner\Dev\VB6_Conversion";

            var files = DirSearch(loc).ToList();

            int i = 0;
            int tot = files.Count;
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i++ + "/" + tot);

                if (file.EndsWith(".vb"))
                {

                    var fileData = File.ReadAllText(file);
                    ParseFile(fileData,file);
                }
            }

            var outFile = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "out.text");


            using (var fl = new StreamWriter(outFile))
            {

                Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n");
                foreach (var a in inUse)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(a);
                    fl.WriteLine(a);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n\n\nPress any key...");
            Console.Read();

        }

        static IEnumerable<string> DirSearch(string rootDir) 
        {

            foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(rootDir,"*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                yield return file;
            }
        }


        static void ParseFile(string file, string filename)
        {

            var regex1 = @".*Sub .*\(.*\)(.*\r\n)*?.*End Sub";
            var regex2 = @".*Function .*\(.*\)(.*\r\n)*?.*End Function";

            var rx1 = new Regex(regex1, RegexOptions.Multiline);
            var rx2 = new Regex(regex2,RegexOptions.Multiline);

            var mc1 = rx1.Matches(file);
            var mc2 = rx2.Matches(file);

            for (int i = 0; i < mc1.Count; i++)
                FuncTest(mc1[i].Value,filename,file,mc1[i].Index);
            for (int i = 0; i < mc2.Count; i++)
                FuncTest(mc2[i].Value,filename,file,mc2[i].Index);

        }

        static int findLineNum(string text, int index)
        {
            var s = text.Substring(0, index);

            return s.Count(x => x == '\n');
        }

        static void FuncTest(string text, string filename, string fullFile, int index)
        {
            var firstLine = Regex.Split(text,"\r\n")[0];

            var regex = @"ByRef ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)";
            var matches = Regex.Matches(firstLine, regex);

            var variables = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
            {
                variables.Add(matches[i].Groups[1].Value);
            }

            foreach (var variable in variables)
            {
                if (!variableInUse(text, variable))
                    continue;

                var line = findLineNum(fullFile, index);
                var fln = filename.PadRight(120);
                var vln = variable.PadRight(40);

                var ot = "Variable in use: {0}, file: {1}, line: {2}";
                inUse.Add(String.Format(ot, vln, fln,line));
            }

        }

        static bool variableInUse(string text, string variable)
        {
            var regex = String.Format(@"^\t*{0} ?=", variable);

            foreach (var line in Regex.Split(text, "\r\n"))
            {
                if (Regex.IsMatch(line, regex))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```